# Input box with multiple match keywords for cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, contains

I am trying to make my contains search better by having only one input instead of three, and to match with all entered words individually.

As of now I have three inputs where I could enter one words individually in each box and am able to search/match with all of them at once. E.g. "Cat", "Dog", "Horse".

What I would like is to only have one input and search "Cat Dog Horse" but to match them individually as "Cat", "Dog", "Horse".

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grLzke2s/

```js
function setValue() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputID").value;
  var inputValue2 = document.getElementById("inputID2").value;
  var inputValue3 = document.getElementById("inputID3").value;
  $('td:contains(' + inputValue + '):contains(' + inputValue2 + '):contains(' + inputValue3 + ')').css("color", "red");
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<text>Keywords:</text><br>
<input id="inputID" value="Dog"></input>
<input id="inputID2" value="Horse"></input>
<input id="inputID3" value="Cat"></input>
<button onclick="setValue()">Use</button>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Horse Dog Panda Mouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Elephant Mouse Panda Eagle</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dog Fox Cat Horse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cat Elephant Eagle Fox</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Actual: Works but I need three separate inputs to match with three different words.

Expected: To only have one input and be able to match with all entered words individually.

Comment: If you just enter _just_ "Fox" into the search bar does it highlight the 3rd and 4th cell, or nothing at all?

Comment: Idea is to highlight all instances of "Fox".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string by spaces and re-[join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them to build the [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) string.

e.g.

```js
function setValue() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputID").value;
  if (!inputValue)
    return;

  var selector = "td:contains('" + inputValue.split(" ").join("'):contains('") + "')";
  console.log(selector);
  $(selector).css("color", "red");
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<text>Keywords:</text><br>
<input id="inputID" value="Cat Dog Horse"></input>

<button onclick="setValue()">Use</button>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Horse Dog Panda Mouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Elephant Mouse Panda Eagle</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dog Fox Cat Horse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cat Elephant Eagle Fox</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To change the condition from *and* to *or* you just need to separate the selectors with a comma.

e.g.

```
var selector = "td:contains('" + inputValue.split(" ").join("'),td:contains('") + "')";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful! Would it also be possible to have hits even if one word is not matching any cell? E.g. "Cat Dog Lion Horse" would match Row 1, 3, 4, and the word "Lion" would be disregarded.

Comment: I assume you mean an "or" condition instead of "and"? I've updated the answer to show how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks again, worked like a charm! Marking as answer. :)

Comment: Would it also be possible to hide what is not matched? E.g. "$(not:selector).closest("tr").hide();". I did like this before when I used several inputs "$('td:contains(' + inputValue3 + ')').closest("tr").hide();" and it would hide the tr of which td matched that value.

Comment: You could hide the unmatched rows using `$("td:not(" + selector + ")").closest("tr").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method without requiring jQuery (because you're apparently only using it for that one statement...). It grabs the cells, iterates over them, and checks their text content (using the array method [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)) against the search phrase. If it matches it adds a `red` class to the cell.

```js
function setValue() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("inputID").value;

  // Split the search phrase into an array
  const arr = inputValue.split(' ');

  // Grab all the cells
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td');

  // For each cell grab the textContent
  cells.forEach(cell => {
    const txt = cell.textContent;

    // `every` returns true if every element (search word)
    // meets the condition (the word is in the cell text)
    if (arr.every(word => txt.includes(word))) {

      // Add the red class to the cell
      cell.classList.add('red');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { padding: 5px; }
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<input id="inputID" value="Dog Horse Cat" />
<button onclick="setValue()">Use</button>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr><td>Horse Dog Panda Mouse</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Elephant Mouse Panda Eagle</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dog Fox Cat Horse</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cat Elephant Eagle Fox</td></tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9k250c7/)

Comment: Thanks for also providing this JS example! :)

Comment: NP. Re your comment on H77's answer. You can change `every` here to [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and get that output. @JoeBerg

Answer (score 0):

You can change input as array like this

```html
<html>
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  th,
  td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
</style>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <text>Keywords:</text><br>
  <input id="input" value=""></input>
  <button onclick="setValue()">Use</button><br><br>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>Horse Dog Panda Mouse</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elephant Mouse Panda Eagle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dog Fox Cat Horse</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cat Elephant Eagle Fox</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    function setValue() {
      var inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
      inputValue = inputValue.split(' ')
      for (let i of inputValue) {
        $('td:contains(' + i + ')', document.body).each(function() {
          $(this).html($(this).html().replace(
            new RegExp(i, 'g'), '<span style="color:red">' + i + '</span>'
          ));
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this code may help you :)